# Change of variable of exponential map in a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-integration, change-of-variable

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional Riemannian mnaifold and $exp_p:B_r(0)\rightarrow B_s(p)$ be the differmorphism, for $p\in M$ and $0\in T_pM$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Then I am confuse about the following integration formula
$$\int_{B_r(0)}f(v)dv=\int_{B_s(p)}f(exp^{-1}_px)|D_xexp^{-1}_p|dx.$$
I think I am doing some wrong in change of variable and I can not correct it. Please Help me by giving me the correct expression. 
Thank you.

Comment: To me, it is fine. What is a problem ?

Comment: I am confuse about the notation $D_x$ in the term $|D_xexp_p^{-1}|$. Is is correct?

Comment: Recall : If $g: V\rightarrow W,\ h: W\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then $\int_{g(U)}\ h=\int_{U\subset V}\ h(g(x)) |D_xg|\ dx$. $D_x$ is a differential of $g$ at a point $x$